# Failed to compare empty string

Tags: php

my code :

```
$disabled = $this->access->get_access('disable_header');
$emptyString = '';
var_dump($emptyString);
var_dump($disabled[0]);
if($disabled[0] == '') die('should be here');
if($disabled[0] == ' ') die('should be here');
die('stop');
```

and the result is :

```
string(0) "" string(1) "" stop
```

all my condition is failed and i don't know why ..
but if i make $emptyString condition :

```
if($emptyString == '') die('should be here');
```

it give me result :

```
should be here
```

if you see the both $dislabled[0] and $emptyString has the same empty string,
but has different length,
if i make $emptyString length to 1 then:

```
$disabled = $this->access->get_access('disable_header');
$emptyString = ' ';
var_dump($emptyString);
var_dump($disabled[0]);
if($disabled[0] == '') die('should be here');
if($disabled[0] == ' ') die('should be here');
die('stop');
```

become :

```
string(1) " " string(1) "" stop
```

i stil failed to compare $disable[0]

what i missed?

====HOW TO RESOLVE===

first i try

```
mb_detect_encoding($disabled[0]);
```

then give me result

```
ASCII
```

then i try :

```
var_dump(hexdec($disabled[0]))
```

then give me result :

```
int(9)
```

i go to ascii table and 9 = TAB key

then now i make condition :

```
if(strcmp($disabled[0],'')) die('should be here');
```

tadaaa .. it show :

```
should be here
```

i think strcmp can work for all enter, tab and space key value ..
any mistake for my opinion?

Comment: Try `var_dump(bin2hex($disabled[0]))`. `""` shouldn't be `(1)` character long.

Comment: The strings are different lengths, but both echo out as empty.  This suggests to me that there's some kind of character encoding issue somewhere, or some non-printable character in the second string.

Comment: id do var_dump(bin2hex($disabled[0])); and got : string(2) "39". What's mean? what condition for $disabled[0] to get TRUE value?

Comment: What character encoding did you save your PHP script in, and what do you get if you do mb_detect_encoding() on the 'disable header' string?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: i do : echo mb_detect_encoding($disabled[0]);exit; got ASCII

Comment: Well... if it's the tab character then `var_dump(bin2hex($disabled[0]));` should have been `"09"`, not `"39"`.

Comment: i do this : var_dump(bin2hex($disabled[0])); echo "<br />";var_dump(hexdec($disabled[0]));exit; i got : string(2) "39"
int(9);

Comment: If you want to ignore whitespace in the values, then you might want to trim() them before comparing.

Comment: cannot .. tab will be always inside, i tried if(trim($disabled[0])=='') got fail too

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
if(empty($disabled[0])) die('should be here');
```

is the better way to check if a variable is empty using PHP.

`""` or `" "` is for JavaScript.